# How to get the size of a directory including its files

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the total size of a directory in flutter, including its files , files in its sub-folders and so on.

I tried to use `Directory.statSync`, but it seems to only return the meta size of the directory itself.

Should I recursively walk the directory to calculate the size? If so, is there a dart package that already does that (I can't find one)?

If not, what more efficient way is available?

Answer (score 19):

This is a example walk a directory recursively (sync version).
Async version can be done with dir.list() and its listen() method.

```
Map<String, int> dirStatSync(String dirPath) {
  int fileNum = 0;
  int totalSize = 0;
  var dir = Directory(dirPath);
  try {
    if (dir.existsSync()) {
      dir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false)
        .forEach((FileSystemEntity entity) {
          if (entity is File) {
            fileNum++;
            totalSize += entity.lengthSync();
          }
        });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }

  return {'fileNum': fileNum, 'size': totalSize};
}
```

Comment: Is this `totalSize` int in bytes or kilobytes?

Comment: In bytes, Of course

Comment: Lol, I was getting some unexpected amount from there that's why I asked.

Comment: lengthAsync method no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more concise if you use `fold` (folder size only option)

```
Future<int> getDirSize(Directory dir) async {
  var files = await dir.list(recursive: true).toList();
  var dirSize = files.fold(0, (int sum, file) => sum + file.statSync().size);
  return dirSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent answer from @sunil-travis, I came up with my own async version of this function:

```
Future<DirStat> getDirStat(String dirPath) async {
    var dir = Directory(dirPath);
    bool exists = await dir.exists();
    if (!exists) {
      return DirStat(numberOfFiles: 0, totalSize: 0);
    }

    int numberOfFiles = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;
    await dir.list(recursive: true, followLinks: false).forEach((FileSystemEntity entity) async {
      if (entity is File) {
        numberOfFiles++;
        totalSize += entity.lengthSync();
      }
    });

    return DirStat(numberOfFiles: numberOfFiles, totalSize: totalSize);
  }
```

And the DirStat class is defined as:

```
class DirStat {
  final int numberOfFiles;
  final int totalSize;

  DirStat({required this.numberOfFiles, required this.totalSize});

  String get totalSizeString => FileSize.getSize(totalSize);
}
```

Note that I'm using the `lengthSync()` method, because the async `length()` method did not work for me at all.

In general, I do not recommend using the sync version of the function that was posted earlier, because on large file hierarchies it may freeze UI for up to several seconds.