# Get application cache size flutter

Tags: flutter

I have written this code to clear the cache from the temporary directory. It works, however, I also want to know the size of the cache in bytes or megabytes. How can I get the size of this directory?

```
 Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
    final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
      cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140112/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-directory-including-its-files) solution.

Comment: this is not for the temporary directory

Comment: You can access to any directory locally (if you have a permissions). All you need is a Directory class instance with corrected path.