# How to delete all files within a directory except files ending in .db

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I want to be able to delete all files within the App cache directory, except files ending with .db.

   ```
    void main() {
        final dir = Directory(dirPath);
        dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
    }
   ```

The above code will delete the entire directory, but I would like to avoid that.

2. How can I get the size of the cache directory in flutter?

Answer (score 2):

```dart
void deleteFilesExceptExtension(String suffix, String path) {
  final dir = Directory(path);
  dir.list(recursive: true).listen((file) {
    if (file is File && !file.path.endsWith(suffix)) file.deleteSync();
  });
}
```

As for a directory's true size, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140112/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-directory-including-its-files).