# how to get directory size with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, size, stat

I'm using flutter and I want to know the capcity size of a directory.
this is my code :

```
  final String directory = (await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path;
```

My question is how to get **directory** size ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514169/5541523

Comment: @Kherel I want to know the capacity of the directory not the busy size

Answer (score 0):

Use `(await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).statSync()` and watch the size value